# Passing the Properties of an Object to method in Vue.Js

Tags: vue.js

I have a Props with array. I would like to Pass the name properties of an Object into a method.

Example: name.Currently this.results.name not returning the value.

```
results: [
       {
          id:"1",
          name: "Alex",
          address: "Japan",

     },
       ],

 data: () => ({    
 clipboard: ''
}),
 props: ['results'],
 methods: {
 edit () {
  this. clipboard = this.results.name
 },
```

Comment: if results is an array `this.results.name` is invalid js, you need to do: `this.results[0].name` or whatever index you want

Comment: Great, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your `results` is array. You should use by index `this.results[0].name`